# Drawbacks of delay

Tags: arduino, delay, pwm

With the following:

```
Serial.begin(9600);
```

I am printing two values:

```
Serial.print(Input); 
Serial.println(Output);
delay(100);
```

I am measuring temperature and PWM signal.

What are the drawbacks of using delay?

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of drawbacks of using delay :

- Inaccuracy
- Unable to multitask

There is one good way to go make a delay without using `delay()`, it's by using `millis()`. See [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/overview) for great examples of why `millis()` is better than `delay()` and how to maximize its capability.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually fine to use `delay()` in simple programs. However, imagine you have 4 tasks:

- T1 which you want to execute every 2s
- T2 which you want to execute every 3s
- T3 which you want to execute every 3.5s
- Serial read task, which should read serial input as soon as it arrives

How would you deal with that using `delay()`? It is much better to use approach based on `millis()` or `micros()` functions, like [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay), or use the [elapsedMillis library](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ElapsedMillis), which under the hood does the same, but makes a code a bit more readable.

The main idea, is that you want to have a sort of timers, that store a time elapsed from last reset. You check the state of these timers in every iteration of the `loop()` function, and if they finish, you execute associated task:

```
void loop() {
  if(isTimerDone(Tim1)) {
    T1();
    resetTimer(Tim1);
  }
  if(isTimerDone(Tim2)) {
    T2();
    resetTimer(Tim2);
  }
  if(isTimerDone(Tim3)) {
    T3();
    resetTimer(Tim3);
  }
  readSerialPort();
}
```

That way it is very easy to change timing for each task, as it is independent of other tasks. It is also easy to add more tasks to the program.

It is also true, that `delay()` (but also `millis()`) are innacurat,e in a sense that you are not guaranteed to have an exact timing. To be sure that a task is executed **exactly** after given time, you need to use interrupts, like in [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Timer1) (Arduino Playground on Timer1).